# Update text with submitted data w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form on a page. I have a link acting as submit button. The value is sent to a php page via ajax where the value is set into a session.

After submit I swap the form with text field where the text is displayed. How do I use the text from the submitted form to display withing `<pre></pre>` tags?

```
$("#btnPreview").click(function() {
    var custM = $("#inviteMsg").val();          
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "msg="+custM
    });     
});

<div id="customMsgPreview">
    <div class="rollSec">
    <pre>
      // SUBMITTED TEXT NEEDS TO APPEAR HERE 
      '.$tstLnk.'
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.ajax`'s `success` callback.

```
var custM = $("#inviteMsg").val(); 
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "msg="+custM,
    success: function(response){
        $('#customMsgPreview').find('pre').html(custM);
    }
});
```

You can also put `response` from the ajax page in the `pre` tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass success callback:

```
success: function (text) {
  $('#customMsgPreview pre').html(text);
}
```